# c statements to assembly

Tags: c, assembly, avr

for a assigment i need to translate some C declarations to assembly using only AVR directives.

I'm wondering if anyone could give me some advice on learning how to do this.

For example:

translate 'char c;' and 'char* d;' to assembly statements

Please note, this is the first week im learning assembly,

Any help/advice would be appreciated

Comment: What advice did your teacher(s) already give you ?  How far have you got with that advice and your own efforts ?

Comment: `char c;` is a variable definition; it's not a statement (it doesn't actually **do** anything).   `a = b + c;` would be a statement.

Comment: Im sorry, changed it to declarations. My teacher didn't really gave any advice, and i won't be able to ask for any either since we are having a week vacation.. The assignments only includes declarations that have to be translated into assembly

Comment: What is going on with these -1's. I have been seeing an increasing number of them for no apparent reason.  How is this bad question?

Comment: @linuxuser27 same here. But we can always vote up to correct.

Answer (score 2):

First, `char c;` and `char* d;` are declarations not statements.

What you can do is dump the assembly output of your C program with the `avr-gcc` option `-S`:

```
# Dump assembly to stdout
avr-gcc -mmcu=your_avr_mcu -S -c source.c -o -
```

Then you can reuse the relevant assembly output parts to create inline assembler statements.

Look here on how to write inline assember with `avr-gcc`:

http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/inline_asm.html

Comment: I do not have any c program available to dump. I only have statements on paper

Comment: @Brainscrewer the whole idea is you have to write the C statements in the `source.c` and see how they are translated so you can reuse them...

Answer (score 0):

Without a compiler that you can disassemble from (avr-gcc is easy to come by), it may be difficult to try to understand what happens when a high level language is compiled.

you are simply declaring that you want a variable or an address when you use declarations like that.  that doesnt necessarily, immediately, place something in assembly.  often dead code and other things are removed from code by the compiler.  Other times it is not until the very end of the compile process that you know where your variable may end up.  Sometimes a char only ever lives in a register, so for a short period of time in the program that variable has a home.  Sometimes there is a longer life the variable has to have a home the whole time the program is running and there are not enough registers to keep it in one forever so it will get a memory location allocated to it.

Likewise a pointer is an address which also lives in registers or in memory locations.

If you dont have a compiler where you can experiment with adding C code and seeing what happens.  And even if you do you need to get the instruction set documentation for the desired processor family.

http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc0856.pdf

Look at the add operation for example add rd,rr, and it shows you that d and r are both between 0 and 31 so you could have add r10,r23.  And looking at the operation that means that r10 = r10 + r23.  If you had char variables that you wanted to add together in C this is one of the instructions the compiler might use.

There are two lds instructions a single 16 bit word version and one that takes two 16 bit words. (usually the assembler chooses that for you).  rd is between 0 and 31 and k is an address in the memory space.  If you have a global variable declared it will likely be accessed using lds or sts.  So K is a pointer, a fixed pointer.  Your char * in C can turn into a fixed number at compile time depending on what you do with that pointer in your code.  If it is a dynamic thing then look at the flavors of ld and st, that use register pairs.  So you might see a char * pointer turn into a pair of registers or a pair of memory locations that hold the pointer itself then it might use  the x, y, or z register pairs, see ld and st, and maybe an adiw to find an offset to that pointer before using ld or st.

I have a simulator http://github.com/dwelch67/avriss.  but it needs work, not fully debugged (unless you want to learn the instruction set through examining a simulator and its potentinal bugs).  simavr and some others are out there that you can use to watch your code execute.  http://gitorious.org/simavr